# Django returning from request and running task in background

Tags: django, cron, request

I have a task that will take ~10-20 minutes to perform. User clicks a button to perform this action. Is it possible to return from this request and keep running this task in background and when it's done send an email or something.

I know I could set up a queue and cron jobs but it seems too much of a job as only one user will be using this feature.

Also, what are the chances of request timing out or breaking ? Maybe it's an option just not turn off tab and wait ?

Comment: Looks like a good use case for a task queue like [celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Very possible and a good candidate for [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

You'll also probably want to look into [redis](http://redis.io/) for the broker.

From your view you could add a task and have it execute immediately and asynchronously then return an Http response with a "this is happening now" message or whatever you prefer.

You could also use a signal like `post_save` or `pre_save` to trigger the task if you are wanting to do something upon saving an object.

Update: Sorry, re-read the question, you already acknowledged using a queue. If it is running for 10 - 20 minutes it will certainly timeout. Unless you increase the timeout or periodically send something back saying I'm still here. Like a json response. But really this does sound best handled by a task queue.